# How to increase OSRM returned via routes precision from 5 to 7?

Tags: python, python-3.7, polyline, osrm

I need to change the returned route coordinates precision from 5 to 7 decimal points, the following link https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/issues/495#issuecomment-21551491 mentions that enhancing the precision will be coming in a later update, couldn't figure out how to increase the precision though

Code:

```
import requests
import polyline
import json

url = "http://localhost:5000/route/v1/driving/35.8582051,32.0335058;35.8581983,32.0335119"
r = requests.get(url)
res = r.json()
print(polyline.decode(res['routes'][0]['geometry']))
```

Output:

```
[(32.03353, 35.85807), (32.03353, 35.85807)]
```

Answer (score 0):

the enhancement of polyline response has been done via the update v5.5.0 now you can utilize the response of the geometries parameter set to polyline6  in the api by adding it to the header of the api call. additional precision might be added to 7 decimal points in later updates possibly polyline7.

`

```
import requests
import polyline
import json
url = "http://localhost:5000/route/v1/driving/35.8582051,32.0335058;35.8581983,32.0335119?geometries=polyline6"
r = requests.get(url)
res = r.json()
polyline_string = res.routes[0].geometry
print(polyline.decode(polyline6_string,6))
```

`